# Replace values in a submatrix in Julia

Tags: matlab, julia

Is there an efficient way of coding other than what I did below while converting matlab code to Julia?  Especially when the `parent_matrix` is of the size `2000X2000` and `inner_matrix` is of size `800X1`?

Matlab:

```
parent_matrix(inner_matrix(:),inner_matrix(:)) = replace_matrix;
```

Julia:

```
ind_inner_vec=reshape(inner_matrix,size(inner_matrix)[1].*size(inner_matrix)[2],1)
z=1
for x in ind_inner_vec
    for y in ind_inner_vec
        parent_matrix[y,x]=replace_matrix[z]
        z=z+1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly

```
parent_matrix[vec(inner_matrix),vec(inner_matrix)] = replace_matrix
```

will do what you want. Note that the `vec` is only needed because you said `inner_matrix` is a column matrix - if it was actually a vector, it wouldn't be needed.